# Start a task process for group except "created by"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have created a custom feedback/approval workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 (using SharePoint Online) that assigns a task to a group (Directors).  How do I get the system to assign a task to each member of the group EXCEPT the director that created the item?